# Is there a way to place the "Add new comment" link where I want?

Tags: 7, theming, comments, navigation

Is there a way to place the "Add new comment" link where I want in my content type? I'd like the link to be between two already existing fields in the content type. Is there some type of way to add this link via a field? Please help. This issue has been killing me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use hide and render to hide/show individual fields.
http://tjegz.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/132/

This will allow you to place things in any order in the tpl file

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hard to do that on a phone sometimes

Comment: Yes, it is difficult in mobile, but you can do it in PC.